# Find $\int \csc^2(x) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I did:

\begin{align}
& \int \csc^2(x) \,dx \\
= {} &\int \left(\frac 1 {\sin(x)}\right)^2 \, dx\\
= {} & \int (\sin(x)^{-1})^2 \, dx\\
= {} & \int \sin(x)^{-2} \, dx\\
= {} & \frac{\sin(x)^{-1}}{-1} \cdot \int \sin(x) \\
= {} & -\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cdot -\cos(x) \\
= {} & \cot(x)
\end{align}

But the right answer is $-\cot(x)$. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I question how you went from the fourth to fifth line.

Comment: @John I tried to apply a kind of chain rule. I suppose that's wrong... how would you solve this?

Comment: @MarkRead you cannot do "chain" rule in integration, no such thing exists like this

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239808/integral-of-cosec-squared-operatornamecosec2x-csc2x

Comment: @KSplitX Well $u$ sub is the chain rule for integration.

Comment: @ZacharySelk More like change of variables but yeah I guess that works

Comment: @KSplitX $u$ sub is literally the chain rule in reverse

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$\frac {1}{\sin^2 (x)}=-\frac {-\sin^2(x)-\cos^2 (x)}{\sin^2 (x)} $$

$$=-\frac {d}{dx}\frac {\cos (x)}{\sin (x)} $$

Comment: how'd you get to step 2?

Comment: @MarkRead $(u/v)'=(u'v-uv')/v^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I was puzzled by this step:
$$
\int \sin(x)^{-2} \, dx = \frac{\sin(x)^{-1}}{-1} \cdot \int \sin(x) \,dx \text{ ?}
$$
Then I realized you were trying to apply a sort of chain rule.

If you have something like $\displaystyle \int (5x+3)^{12} \,dx$ you can say that it's equal to $\dfrac{(5x+3)^{13}}{13}\cdot \dfrac 1 5$ and that's an application of the chain rule for differentiation. Or a bit more elaborately:
$$
\int(5x+4)^{12} \, dx = \int u^{12} \, \left(\frac{du} 5\right) = \frac{u^{13}}{13} \cdot \frac 1 5 + \text{constant}
$$
and like all "$u$-substitutions" that is an application of the chain rule.

But consider this:
$$\require{cancel}
\xcancel{\frac d {dx} \left( \frac{\sin(x)^{-1}}{-1} \cdot \int\sin(x)\, dx \right) = \sin(x)^{-2} \cdot \sin(x)}
$$
The problem is that you're multiplying two functions and then differentiating what you get, and for that you need the product rule. You can't just differentiate the two separately.

Comment: Wow! I didn't you can do that.